# Informatica metadata table - Primary key column from target table

Tags: informatica

Couple of tables in our Database doesm't has any key. However, key was created in target table at informatica level.

Now my need is, need to identify informatica metadata table where I can find tgt table and corresponding column name marked as key.

Kindly suggest

Comment: Why do you have tables with no PK? Why do you need to find this particular metadata table? Do you want to update it directly?

Comment: These tables are created long not sure why it was created like that. We planed to add primary key at database level so to identify the primary key I want to look for informatica metadata tables

Comment: Find _Metadata Exchange (MX) Views_ in the documentation. However, can't you open the target definition in PowerCenter and see which port is marked as `PRIMARY KEY`?

Comment: We have around 600 tables it will take more manula effort to check each mapping. Hence we opted for metadata tables

Comment: Found answer: Collected data from REP_TARG_TBL_COLS - by Thilak

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Metadata Exchange (MX) Views:

- `REP_TARG_TBLS` provides a list of targets in the repository
- `REP_TARG_TBL_COLS` provides the properties of columns defined for the target tables in a data warehouse or data mart

  - It contains a column `COLUMN_KEYTYPE` that takes of the following values: `Primary Key`, `Not a Key`, `Foreign Key`, `Primary` and `Foreign Key`.

Source: [PowerCenter 8.6.1. Repository Guide](https://mysupport.informatica.com/docs/DOC-1679) (login required)